# docker-compose unable to start

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I had previous success following this walkthrough on creating a series of docker containers that allowed me to use MySQLI, PHP, and phpmyadmin:

https://gist.github.com/jcavat/2ed51c6371b9b488d6a940ba1049189b

I decided to try it again and make a few tweaks, such as trying to PDO instead of MYSQLI.

Starting with the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
www:
    build: .
    ports: 
        - "8001:80"
    volumes:
        - ./www:/var/www/html/
    links:
        - db
    networks:
        - default
db:
    image: mysql:5.7.13
    ports: 
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: myDb
        MYSQL_USER: user
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    volumes:
        - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
        - default
phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links: 
        - db:db
    ports:
        - 8000:80
    environment:
        MYSQL_USER: user
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
volumes:
  persistent:
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0.30-apache 
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

Now if you'll reference the tutorial link above, I altered the myDb.sql file.  Instead of creating the table called 'Person', I created a table called 'users'.  I did not want to paste the whole myDb.sql file, but here is the CREATE TABLE portion:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `department` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(30),
  `phone` varchar(30),
  `addDate` datetime(),
  `addUser` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastLogin` datetime()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then the insert:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `username`, `email`, `department`, `title`, `phone`, `addDate`, `addUser`) VALUES (1, 'William', 'Wheaton', 'usa.wwheaton', 'usa.wwheaton@gmail.com', 'Engineering', 'Ensign', '7577771212', NOW(), 'admin');
```

I also added another create table script that I won't include, as this question is getting long.

Upon running the command 'docker-compose up', I receive the following error:

```
Building www
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 74, in _execute
  File "subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
  File "subprocess.py", line 418, in run
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain', 'get']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 129, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 35, in get
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 87, in _execute
dockerpycreds.errors.StoreError: Credentials store docker-credential-osxkeychain exited with "The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.".

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
 File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
 File "compose/cli/main.py", line 127, in perform_command
 File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1080, in up
 File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1076, in up
 File "compose/project.py", line 475, in up
 File "compose/service.py", line 358, in ensure_image_exists
 File "compose/service.py", line 1082, in build
 File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 251, in build
 File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 307, in _set_auth_headers
 File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 96, in resolve_authconfig
 File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 146, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
docker.errors.DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('Credentials store docker-credential-osxkeychain exited with "The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.".',)
[49981] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

I am not sure why this is failing to run.  I am not even sure why the error message states that I am using the wrong name or passphrase.

What am I missing or what do I need to fix that will get this to run properly?

Comment: Can you login to docker hub? `docker login`

Comment: Your app thinks it is still running on MacOS (the errors are KeyChain related). Did you previously run the application on your host? Maybe it saved temporary files that make the app still think it is on Mac... You should find out why "/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain" is called. This file is not present on systems other than MacOS

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is an issue with docker build; cos, the docker hub login must fail in your case (this might have happened with multiple docker login registry in your config file)

If you want a quick fix, delete the `.docker/config.json` file and login docker before you run `docker-compose up`

```
sudo rm ~/.docker/config.json

docker login

docker-compose up
```

**Note:** a new `~/.docker/config.json` file will be created on your successful login