# Docker: error using docker-compose up on the official getting started tutorial

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and I'm trying to follow this simple "getting started" tutorial https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/ using a newly first time installation of docker (for Windows 10) dowloaded from here: https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows/.

At step 4 of this tutorial i get this error:

```
PS D:\composetest> docker-compose up
Building web
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\docker\credentials\store.py", line 80, in _execute
  File "subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
  File "subprocess.py", line 487, in run
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files\\Docker\\Docker\\resources\\bin\\docker-credential-desktop.EXE', 'list']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 72, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 128, in perform_command
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 1078, in up
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 1074, in up
  File "compose\project.py", line 548, in up
  File "compose\service.py", line 367, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose\service.py", line 1106, in build
  File "site-packages\docker\api\build.py", line 261, in build
  File "site-packages\docker\api\build.py", line 308, in _set_auth_headers
  File "site-packages\docker\auth.py", line 302, in get_all_credentials
  File "site-packages\docker\credentials\store.py", line 71, in list
  File "site-packages\docker\credentials\store.py", line 93, in _execute
docker.credentials.errors.StoreError: Credentials store docker-credential-desktop exited with "error listing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `Impossibile trovare elemento.`".
[13284] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

EDIT: The accepted solution in [docker-compose unable to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267890/docker-compose-unable-to-start), unfortunately, did not work.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have the same issue...

Try:
$nano ~/.docker/config.json
In this file change credsStore to credStore

Now run your docker-compose. If its not works try sudo

Comment: omg, it's weird but it works

Comment: I believe this is equivalent to just removing the property. As `credsStore` is the valid name. Changing it just makes the docker not use the defined credentials store.

Answer (score 0):

try to add to the environment path :

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin
```

If you are using WSL2 run  this command

```
sudo  ln -s /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/docker-credential-desktop.exe /usr/bin/docker-credential-desktop.exe
```